# How can i convert a Array list to object?

Tags: java

I have to sort object which contains name/surname/date/price/paid by surnames in alphabetical order, but when I sort the object using Collection.sort and try to rewrite the object, it says that -java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to dip107.Student. 
Student is the name of object (class Student implements Serializable{).

```
public Student(String name, String surname, String date, double price, double paid) {
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.date = date;
    this.price = price;
    this.paid = paid;
}

public static void sortsurname() {
    List<String> sort  = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename));
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("temp"));
        Student s;
        boolean EOF = false;
        while (!EOF) {
            try {
                s = (Student) 
                in.readObject();
                sort.add(s.surname.toString());
                Collections.sort(sort);
                out.writeObject(sort);
            } catch (EOFException e) {
                EOF = true;
            }
        }
        in.close();
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
    new File(filename).delete();
    new File("temp").renameTo(new File(filename));
}
```

Comment: An ArrayList is already an object

Comment: `s = (Student) 
                in.readObject();` You're likely reading in an ArrayList object but erroneously casting it as a Student object. You can't do that.

Comment: I'm sorry, new at programming. Ok, then why doesnt it allow me to rewrite the original object?

Comment: **The original object already is an ArrayList**, and it's letting you read it

Comment: `ArrayList<Student> studentList = (ArrayList<Student>) 
                in.readObject();`

Comment: If i implement a compareTo method, how can i make them compare each Students surnames first letter? And if i have not defined number of students, that is, if i add new Student via other method , how can it compare the new entry with other students?

Comment: Although not relevant for a solution, object serialization should not be used anymore since it comes with serious security issues. You should move to a representation like XML or JSON.

Comment: Rewrite? Casting doesn’t work like that. Casting only tells the compiler not to complain. It doesn’t convert anything.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code. The point is what you have written in the file that you are reading from. You can write the sorting either by implementing **Comparable** interface in Student or by passing a **Comparator** in **Collections.sort()** method.

```
import java.io.EOFException;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class SomeClass {


    public static void main(String args[])throws Exception{
        Student s1 = new Student("zksjdf","sdfkj");
        Student s2 = new Student("yui","aqws");
        List<Student> s = new ArrayList<>();
        s.add(s1);
        s.add(s2);
        ObjectOutputStream out1 = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("out1.txt"));
        ObjectOutputStream out2 = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("out2.txt"));
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("out1.txt"));

        out1.writeObject(s); // line 27

        boolean EOF = false;
        while (!EOF) {
            try {
                List<Student> ss = (List<Student>) in.readObject(); // this cast depends on what you'r writing in the file on line 27
                Collections.sort(ss, new Comparator<Student>() {

                    @Override
                    public int compare(Student o1, Student o2) {
                        return o1.lastName.compareTo(o2.lastName);
                    }
                });
                System.out.println(ss);
                out2.writeObject(ss);

            } catch (EOFException e) {
                EOF = true;
            }
        }
        in.close();
        out1.close();
        out2.close();
    }

}


class Student implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6960348259392457529L;
    String lastName;
    String firstName;
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public Student(String lastName, String firstName) {
        super();
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{"+lastName + ", " + firstName+"}";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but i dont understand why are u adding Student s1 and s2. In my case, i have already made a class which contains all the Students names/surnames.. . My apologies for asking stupid questions :)

Comment: This is just to illustrate my point. I wanted to show the actual content of `out1.txt` file. Since the file contains the serialized list, we type-cast the deserialized object to the `List<Student>` and not `Student` like you did in `s = (Student)in.readObject();`

Comment: Ok, i rewrote the code and it works, but it doesnt sort. Maybe it doesnt like the :  @Override
                    public int compare(Student o1, Student o2) {
                        return o1.lastName.compareTo(o2.lastName);
                    }

Comment: No, `@Override
                    public int compare(Student o1, Student o2) {
                        return o1.lastName.compareTo(o2.lastName);
                    }` is correct. Make sure you write it correctly. and pass the input correctly.